# "Error: Preset jest.preset.js not found" when using IntelliJ to run Jest tests in NX Workspace

Tags: angular, jestjs, ts-jest

I have an NX workspace with Node + Angular libraries.  When upgrading from NX version 13.x to 14.x, NX reconfigured Jest through its automated migration process.

When running the project:test generator, my jest tests work as expected.  However, when trying to run unit tests directly through the IDE (IntelliJ), I get the following error:

```
Error: ● Validation Error:

  Preset jest.preset.js not found.

  Configuration Documentation:
  https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
```

The project is setup with project level configuration files, as shown below.

```js
module.exports = {
   coverageDirectory: '<path>',
   displayName      : '<name>',
   globals          : {
      'ts-jest': {
         stringifyContentPathRegex: '\\.(html|svg)$',
         tsconfig                 : '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json'
      }
   },

   setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/test-setup.ts'],

   snapshotSerializers    : [
      'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/no-ng-attributes',
      'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/ng-snapshot',
      'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/html-comment'
   ],
   transform              : {
      '^.+.(ts|mjs|js|html)$': 'jest-preset-angular'
   },
   transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!.*.mjs$)'],
   preset                 : '../../../../../jest.preset.ts'
};
```

The preset file exits and looks like:

```js
const nxPreset = require('@nrwl/jest/preset');

module.exports = { ...nxPreset };
```

I also have a global `jest.config.ts` file.  This file does have a reference to `jest.preset.js` which does not exist within its scope.  Also, not existing, is a globally scoped `test-setup.ts` file.  Shown below:

```js
const { getJestProjects } = require('@nrwl/jest');

module.exports = {
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      astTransformers: {
        before: [
          'jest-preset-angular/build/InlineFilesTransformer',
          'jest-preset-angular/build/StripStylesTransformer'
        ]
      },
      stringifyContentPathRegex: '\\.(html|svg)$',
      tsconfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json'
    }
  },
  preset             : 'jest.preset.js',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/test-setup.ts'],
  snapshotSerializers: [
    'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/no-ng-attributes',
    'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/ng-snapshot',
    'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/html-comment'
  ],
  projects: [
    ...getJestProjects(),
    //Lots of projects
  ]
};
```

I imagine that there was something awry in the migration, but I do not understand jest configuration well enough to know how to deconflict these.  There are multiple issues in the global config file, however when I eliminate the global config file I get a host of other errors (as in it appears that it tries to run my ts tests in js).

Any thoughts as to how I could rectify this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome this problem by adjusting the "working directory" in my test configuration.

[image]

I was getting the error `Preset ../../jest.preset.ts not found` so I found the `jest.preset.ts` file in my project and set the working directory of my configuration to be two folders "below" that file.

E.g.

- My test file is in `src/app/my-app/A/B/C`
- My `jest.preset.ts` file is in `src`
- The error was `Preset ../../jest.preset.ts not found`
- Set the working directory to `src/app/my-app` (so the test runner will "step up" to the `src` folder)

[image]